# heroku saying index.html does not exist when running MERN stack project

Tags: heroku, mern

im currently trying to get my MERN stack project running on heroku. My folder structure is

```
personalsite
 client
  build
   indec.html
   ...
   ...
 server
  index.js
  ...
```

and in my index.js i have

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    app.use(express.static("../client/build"));
    app.get("*", (req,res) =>{
        res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
    })
}
```

yet when i push to heroku i get the log

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
```

if anyone knows why this may be happening or what i can do to fix it, that would be very much appreciated.